# contact form in rails - email with out body

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working in a contact form for my website on rails. I send the email and I received the email with the subject, to and from; but the body is blank. Here the code:

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreplay@hybrid-tech.net"
  default to:   "info@hybrid-tech.net"

  def new_message(contact_message)
    @contact_message = contact_message
    mail(subject: "Send it from Hybrid Tech Website - #{@contact_message.subject} ")
  end
end
```

the view

contact_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Name: <%= @contact_message.name %></h1>
    <h1>E-Mail: <%= @contact_message.email %></h1>
    <p>
      Message: <%= @contact_message.body %><br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have and idea what's the problem here.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `contact_email.html.erb` to `new_message.html.erb`.

The view should have the same name as the action in your Mailer.